# directshow filter conncetion fails for X264vfw avc codec to GDCL Mpeg4 Multiplexer

Tags: visual-c++, directshow, video-capture, mp4

i need to make one directshow application to capture mp4 video from source , i am using below graph to do so,

```
Input Stream --> MJPEG Decompressor --> x264vfw H.264/MPEG-4 AVC Codec --> GDCL Mpeg-4 Multiplexor --> File Writer
```

but when connecting filters x264vfw H.264/MPEG-4 AVC Codec And GDCL Mpeg-4 Multiplexor , i get the Error. with HRESULT = -2147220969

Can anybody have any idea on this , how to make it working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error. with HRESULT = -2147220969

This is your error: `0x80040217`: No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection. That is, `VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT`. You are trying to connect unconnectable.

Comment: Hi @Roman R. , Thanks for your reply. this working well with graphEdit , i just using `CLSID_AVICo(D76E2820-1563-11cf-AC98-00AA004C0FA9) to create instance of x264vfw` to create instance for `x264vfw` . is that can be issue??

Comment: Yes this can be an issue. You cannot create VFW encoder using `CLSID`, instead you need to enumerate monikers and create the instance through moniker. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx